# Correct Citation Format for a Bitcoin Transaction

Tags: transactions, address, block, academic-research

When writing an academic style paper where specific bitcoin transactions are used as examples, is there a standard format to "cite" a bitcoin transaction?

If not, what do you think an appropriate format would be?  What data should be included?  What about altcoin chains, what would be different for those chains?

Answer (score 2):

There is none that I'm aware of, but technically speaking, the blockchain and the transaction hash would suffice to find it. It might be nice to add the block height number as well.

Something like:

```
Tx 35779d11b2c5aedc1ada50aaa33aafb53ccc07dae71e6d18a35a0ccb872a0efa, Bitcoin Block 342508
```

Would work as a citation.

Comment: That what I was leaning towards.  However I would lead with the chain and add the self reported date (but not time) base on UTC.

> Bitcoin, Transaction ID 35779d11b2c5aedc1ada50aaa33aafb53ccc07dae71e6d18a35a0ccb872a0efa, Block 342598, 7 Feb 2015